# I could not login into the admin page with predefined username and password in my config.php page

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I could not login into the admin page with predefined username and password in my config.php page. When i try to pass through admin page i am redirected to the exception handling error message rather than rendering in admin.php page.
I used the code from http://www.elated.com/articles/cms-in-an-afternoon-php-mysql/. As i submit my username and password, its not evaluating in admin.php page after getting 'action' from loginpage.
Thank You !

Answer (score 0):

I went through the code. In loginForm.php in /template/admin, the form starts as follows :

```
<form action="admin.php?action=login" method="post" style="width: 50%;">
```

Now, this line causes the data to be submitted to http://example.com/template/admin/admin.php
But admin.php is in the parent directory. This might be the reason, why your server displays an exception handling message, since admin.php is not in /template/admin/. So, I would recommend changing the action attribute to,

```
action="/admin.php?action=login"
```

This would cause the data to be submitted to http://example.com/admin.php and process the data the way it was supposed to be.